# Nagios 4.4.7 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, 22.04, openssl, monitoring

Im trying to install Nagios 4.4.7 from source on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04

Latest updates applied

Everything compiles and installs OK but on starting I get this:

```
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 systemd[1]: Starting Nagios Core 4.4.7...
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Nagios Core 4.4.7
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Copyright (c) 2009-present Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Last Modified: 2022-04-14
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: License: GPL
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Website: https://www.nagios.org
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Reading configuration data...
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]:    Read main config file okay...
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]:    Read object config files okay...
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Running pre-flight check on configuration data...
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Checking objects...
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 8 services.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 1 hosts.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 1 host groups.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 0 service groups.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 1 contacts.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 1 contact groups.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 24 commands.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 5 time periods.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 0 host escalations.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 0 service escalations.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Checking for circular paths...
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 1 hosts
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 0 service dependencies
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 0 host dependencies
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: #011Checked 5 timeperiods
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Checking global event handlers...
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Checking obsessive compulsive processor commands...
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Checking misc settings...
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Total Warnings: 0
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Total Errors:   0
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202580]: Things look okay - No serious problems were detected during the pre-flight check
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 systemd[1]: Started Nagios Core 4.4.7.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: Nagios 4.4.7 starting... (PID=202582)
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: Local time is Mon May 16 16:29:09 UTC 2022
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: LOG VERSION: 2.0
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: qh: Socket '/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.qh' successfully initialized
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: qh: core query handler registered
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: qh: echo service query handler registered
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: qh: help for the query handler registered
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: wproc: Successfully registered manager as @wproc with query handler
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 202585;pid=202585
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 202584;pid=202584
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 202586;pid=202586
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios: wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 202583;pid=202583
May 16 16:29:10 server2204 nagios: Caught SIGSEGV, shutting down...
May 16 16:29:10 server2204 systemd[1]: nagios.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=254/n/a
May 16 16:29:12 server2204 systemd[1]: nagios.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is a standard install, with no configuration apart from default

journelctl -xe:

```
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nagios.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit nagios.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 19738.
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: Nagios 4.4.7 starting... (PID=202582)
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: Local time is Mon May 16 16:29:09 UTC 2022
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: LOG VERSION: 2.0
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: qh: Socket '/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.qh' successfully initialized
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: qh: core query handler registered
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: qh: echo service query handler registered
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: qh: help for the query handler registered
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: wproc: Successfully registered manager as @wproc with query handler
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 202585;pid=202585
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 202584;pid=202584
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 202586;pid=202586
May 16 16:29:09 server2204 nagios[202582]: wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 202583;pid=202583
May 16 16:29:10 server2204 nagios[202582]: Caught SIGSEGV, shutting down...
May 16 16:29:10 server2204 systemd[1]: nagios.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=254/n/a
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit nagios.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 254.
May 16 16:29:12 server2204 systemd[1]: nagios.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit nagios.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: from source, using configure/make etc

Answer (score 0):

this appears to be related to an SSL issue, have confirmed this resolves the issue:

https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/issues/861